# select doesn't works correctly on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7

All :)

I have some piece of code with correctly works on Linux and WinXP

```
int FlowTestIP::do_recvfrom()
{
    int ret;
    struct timeval timeout;// = {2, 0};
    timeout.tv_sec = 2;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    fd_set rfds;
    while(running) {
            FD_ZERO(&rfds);
            FD_SET(m_socket, &rfds);
            ret = select(m_socket + 1, &rfds, 0, 0, &timeout);
            cout << "// select ret = " << ret << " (errno = " << errno << ")" << endl;
            if (ret == -1 || ret == 0) {
                    if (!(ret == 0 && errno == 0))
                            cout << "select ret = " << ret << " (errno = " << errno << ")" << endl;
                    return ret;
            }
            if (FD_ISSET(m_socket, &rfds)) {
                    cout << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                    break;
            }
    }
    return recvfrom(m_socket, in_buf, mtu, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_other, (socklen_t *)&otherAddrSize);
}
```

But in Windows 7 in continues to loop even when client apptication is exited.
Bad output is

> ...
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   FTControlServerThread::run
>   FTControlServerThread::recieved
>   pkt->ft_tos = UCHAR_MAX
>   QFuture::waitForFinished()
>   client alive true
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0

normaly (on WinXP and Linux) output will be

> ...
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   // select ret = 1 (errno = 0)
>   0
>   FTControlServerThread::run
>   FTControlServerThread::recieved
>   pkt->ft_tos = UCHAR_MAX
>   QFuture::waitForFinished()
>   client alive true
>   QFuture::finished

And that is what I am waiting from it.

Has anyone encountered with such a misbehaviour?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. As @JoachimPileborg asked to show how I call this function:

```
FlowTest::recv(char *payload, size_t size)  
{  
...  
    while (running) {  
        len = do_recvfrom(); // it virtual method of class FlowTest  
        if (len == -1 || len == 0) {  
            return len;  
        }  

        if (running && !transport_recv_helper()) {  
            continue;  
        } else {  
            break;  
        }  
    }  
...  
}
```

and recv is called from server GUI

```
void FlowTestServer::runTest(FlowTestServerHelper handler)
{
...
        if ((ret = server->recv(rcvdData, (size_t *)&size)) == -1 || ret == 0 || size == 0) {
            if (server_busy == 0)
                break;
            cout << "can't receive data (size == " << size << "; ret = " << ret << ")" << endl;
            continue;
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Remember that `select` modifies the timeout structure as well as the `fd_set` structures. Also, you should never check for error codes unless the function explicitly failed, as the value then is undefined. And talking about errors, you should not check `errno` on a Windows machine, only `WSAGetLastError` (and like I said before, only when `select` actually returns an error).

Comment: Also, can you please edit your question to show how you call this function? Maybe you could make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot, @JoachimPileborg!!! :)  
It realy modifies timeout struct, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: Using `cout` is allowed to reset `errno`. It doesn't usually, but it can, especially on first use when it has to set up the locale. You need to save the value of `errno` in a temp variable, or use `fprintf` and friends - as a C lib function POSIX controls its behavior.

Secondly: In Windows, you need to use `WSAGetLastError()` not `errno`.

I suggest you make a macro `sock_errno` which will be `(errno)` on Linux/unix, and `(WSAGetLastError())` on Windows. That will enable to you to code in a platform independent manner.

- See here for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737828(v=vs.85).aspx